# Expression Engine - Help with static code inside expression engine ul

Tags: php, html, css, expressionengine, multiple-entries

I've managed to sort the last li issue, but can't seem to now link my last list item back to the latest entry in the specific category. Any ideas?

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="project" limit="6" category_group="1" stop_before="{embed:stop_before}" related_categories_mode="yes" custom_fields="yes"}
{if count == "1"}<ul id="filmStrip">{/if}
<li>
{exp:imgsizer:size src="{project_image}" height="68px" width="137px"}
<a href="{title_permalink='projects-test/view'}"><img src="{sized}" height="{height}" width="{width}" alt=""/></a>
{/exp:imgsizer:size}
<a href="{title_permalink='projects-test/view'}"><p class="thumbTitle">{title}</p></a>
</li>
{if total_results <= '5' AND total_results == count}
    <li>
        <a href="{path='projects-test/view'}/{first_entry_id}"><img src="../../../images/backtostart.jpg" height="68px" width="137px" alt=""/></a>
        <a href="{path='projects-test/view'}/{first_entry_id}"><p class="thumbTitle">Back to start</p></a>
    </li>
{/if}
{if count == total_results}</ul>{/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: OK, I've realised why it's appearing below... it's appearing as a 7th list item, then when there are only 5 or below it's allowed to fit in line. I guess I need to find a way for it to only show if there are less than 6 list items. OR make the ul only show 6 list items... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that you're using the `{count}` and `{total_results}` variables outside of the channel:entries loop, which won't work.

Here's how you can limit the display of the "back" link in this manner, and also link to the first entry in that category (by "first" I assume you mean "newest"):

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="project" limit="6" category_group="1" stop_before="{embed:stop_before}" related_categories_mode="yes" custom_fields="yes"}
{if count == "1"}<ul id="filmStrip">{/if}
<li>
    {exp:imgsizer:size src="{project_image}" height="68px" width="137px"}
    <a href="{title_permalink='projects-test/view'}"><img src="{sized}" height="{height}"   width="{width}" alt=""/></a>
    {/exp:imgsizer:size}
    <a href="{title_permalink='projects-test/view'}"><p class="thumbTitle">{title}</p></a>
</li>
{if count == total_results}
    {if count == "5"}
    {categories show_group="1" limit="1"}
    {exp:query sql="SELECT t.entry_id as first_entry_id FROM exp_channel_titles t LEFT JOIN exp_category_posts c ON t.entry_id = c.entry_id WHERE c.cat_id = {category_id} AND t.status = 'open' ORDER BY t.entry_date DESC LIMIT 1"}
    <li>
        <a href="{path='projects-test/view'}/{first_entry_id}"><img src="../../../images/backtostart.jpg" height="68px" width="137px" alt=""/></a>
        <a href="{path='projects-test/view'}/{first_entry_id}"><p class="thumbTitle">Back to start</p></a>
    </li>
    {/exp:query}
    {/categories}
    {/if}
</ul>{/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I haven't tested this, so let me know if it throws a fit.

**UPDATE:** Things to try to get the "first entry" query to work:

- Add `parse="inward"` to the exp:query tag.
- Try running the SQL query directly via the SQL Manager within the EE control panel (substituting a category_id for the {category_id} variable), and see if that returns the correct entry_id.
- Remember that this code assumes that each project will only have one category assigned to it in that category group.

The nested `{if}` statement I used above *should* work - and it's better to use that than the advanced one you updated your original post with, as it will cause the query statement to run every time.

Comment: Hi, many thanks but this shows nothing. The projects won't list with this code.

Comment: Just a matter of troubleshooting it by removing bits until it works, then adding stuff back in.  This general idea WILL work for you, it's just hard to write it exactly how you need it without the working site to test on.

Comment: Thanks again. I managed to get the last li to show using the revised code in my main post. However I can't seem to link it back to the first project.

Comment: Added some to the original answer.

Comment: Unfortunately none of that worked. I've tried everything in your answer. Many thanks for your persistant help though.

Comment: Can you think why it isn't working for me? It's just displaying nothing at all when I try your code.

Comment: Is debug set to 1 in your index.php file? You should be seeing errors if nothing's displaying at all.

Comment: Debug is set to 1 yes. It's not displaying any errors, just not displaying anything at all.