# Latest entry linking issue - Expression Engine

Tags: php, html, css, loops, expressionengine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Expression Engine - Help with static code inside expression engine ul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871807/expression-engine-help-with-static-code-inside-expression-engine-ul)

I am having problems linking to a latest entry from a title_permalink "view" page. I have created a link on this page but need it to link to the latest entry in that specific category. This is my code:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="project" limit="6" category_group="1" stop_before="{embed:stop_before}" related_categories_mode="yes" custom_fields="yes"}
{if count == "1"}<ul id="filmStrip">{/if}
<li>
{exp:imgsizer:size src="{project_image}" height="68px" width="137px"}
<a href="{title_permalink='projects-test/view'}"><img src="{sized}" height="{height}" width="{width}" alt=""/></a>
{/exp:imgsizer:size}
<a href="{title_permalink='projects-test/view'}"><p class="thumbTitle">{title}</p></a>
</li>
{if total_results <= '5' AND total_results == count}
    <li>
        <a href="{path='projects-test/view'}/{first_entry_id}"><img src="../../../images/backtostart.jpg" height="68px" width="137px" alt=""/></a>
        <a href="{path='projects-test/view'}/{first_entry_id}"><p class="thumbTitle">Back to start</p></a>
    </li>
{/if}
{if count == total_results}</ul>{/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I would've thought this would be easy enough but it seems not! My code is the code inside the if total_results conditional.

I've tried everything, basically I have numerous projects, and once the end of projects is reached, there is a button that says "Back to start of projects". I need this to go back to the beginning in a loop so to speak.

**EDIT:**
This is my code after adding the proposed solution below.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="project" limit="6" category_group="1" stop_before="{embed:stop_before}" related_categories_mode="yes" custom_fields="yes"}
{if count == "1"}<ul id="filmStrip">{/if}
<li>
{exp:imgsizer:size src="{project_image}" height="68px" width="137px"}
<a href="{title_permalink='projects-test/view'}"><img src="{sized}" height="{height}" width="{width}" alt=""/></a>
{/exp:imgsizer:size}
<a href="{title_permalink='projects-test/view'}"><p class="thumbTitle">{title}</p></a>
</li>
{if total_results <= '5' AND total_results == count}
{categories show_group="1" limit="1"}
{exp:query sql="SELECT t.entry_id as first_entry_id FROM exp_channel_titles t LEFT JOIN exp_category_posts c ON t.entry_id = c.entry_id WHERE c.cat_id = {category_id} AND t.status != 'closed' ORDER BY t.entry_date DESC LIMIT 1"}
    <li>
        <a href="{path='projects-test/view'}/{first_entry_id}"><img src="../../../images/backtostart.jpg" height="68px" width="137px" alt=""/></a>
        <a href="{path='projects-test/view'}/{first_entry_id}"><p class="thumbTitle">Back to start</p></a>
    </li>
{/exp:query}
{/categories}
{/if}
{if count == total_results}</ul>{/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Here is the link to the page:

http://www.mclh.co.uk/index.php/projects-test/view/199

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the issue with my answer to the [previous related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871807/expression-engine-help-with-static-code-inside-expression-engine-ul) was that when using the **related_categories_mode** parameter, `{categories}` isn't available. But I realized that all you need for the query is the `group_id` for the category group anyway. So, try this:

```
{if total_results <= '5' AND total_results == count}
{exp:query sql="SELECT t.entry_id as first_entry_id FROM exp_channel_titles t LEFT JOIN exp_category_posts p ON t.entry_id = p.entry_id LEFT JOIN exp_categories c ON c.cat_id = p.cat_id WHERE c.group_id = 1 AND t.status != 'closed' ORDER BY t.entry_date DESC LIMIT 1"}
    <li>
        <a href="{path='projects-test/view'}/{first_entry_id}"><img src="../../../images/backtostart.jpg" height="68px" width="137px" alt=""/></a>
        <a href="{path='projects-test/view'}/{first_entry_id}"><p class="thumbTitle">Back to start</p></a>
    </li>
{/exp:query}
{/if}
```

**UPDATE**: or, if you're able to pass the main entry's `{category_id}` via an embed, you can do this:

```
{if total_results <= '5' AND total_results == count}
{exp:query sql="SELECT t.entry_id as first_entry_id FROM exp_channel_titles t LEFT JOIN exp_category_posts c ON t.entry_id = c.entry_id WHERE c.cat_id = {embed:category_id} AND t.status != 'closed' ORDER BY t.entry_date DESC LIMIT 1"}
    <li>
        <a href="{path='projects-test/view'}/{first_entry_id}"><img src="../../../images/backtostart.jpg" height="68px" width="137px" alt=""/></a>
        <a href="{path='projects-test/view'}/{first_entry_id}"><p class="thumbTitle">Back to start</p></a>
    </li>
{/exp:query}
{/if}
```

Comment: Hello. Many thanks for this, I appreciate your help but it doesn't seem to be working for me. I'll paste my current code inside the main question and a link to the page so you can see, it's not displaying anything.

Comment: John - I think the issue is **related_categories_more**.  The `{categories}` tag is not available when using that mode, hence our problem.

Comment: Hmm, I need related categories mode on to pull all of the projects from that category, if i get rid of it, it's only displaying one project... Is there a way around this?

Comment: Just revised my answer with new code.

Comment: Hmm... I can't thank you enough for helping me to get this to work but there is one last issue. Maybe I didn't explain my question properly, I need it to link back to the latest entry in the specific category. At the moment it links back fine, but it's linking to the latest entry overall which is entry id 200. But I need it to link the the latest entry in whatever category the user is in. Is there a bit of code I can add in or is this not possible?

Comment: Aah, I see.  I thought you just needed to link back to the first entry in the *category group* the current entry is in. Are you embedding this template? If so, you could pass the `{category_id}` via the embed, and then use that in the query. In which case, my older query statement would be the way to go. Will update answer again.

Comment: Seems to be throwing back an error: Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND t.status != 'closed' ORDER BY t.entry_date DESC LIMIT 1' at line 1

SELECT t.entry_id as first_entry_id FROM exp_channel_titles t LEFT JOIN exp_category_posts c ON t.entry_id = c.entry_id WHERE c.cat_id = AND t.status != 'closed' ORDER BY t.entry_date DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: You're missing the cat_id in the query. Are you embedding this template and passing the category_id via an embed parameter?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean? The category id will change dependant on which category the user is on.

Comment: Add to your embed tag: `category_id="{categories show_group="1" limit="1"}{category_id}{/categories}"`.

Comment: I understand you now. Works like a treat. Thanks very much for all of your help, i'd have been lost without it. I really appreciate it! Where can I learn about expression engine query tags?

Comment: Glad that worked! You can read up on the [query module in the docs](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/query/), but most of the work here is knowing some [basic MySQL syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).